# UIImagePickerController doesn't return a live photo in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios13, phlivephoto

My code has stopped working in iOS 13. In my UIImagePickerController delegate I look to see if the media type returned (the type of thing the user chose) is a live photo. If it is, I use the `.livePhoto` key to get the PHLivePhoto. This used to work. But in iOS 13 this key's value is always `nil`. How can I get the live photo that the user chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regard this change in behavior as a bug. However, if you have permission to access the user's photo library, you can use the `.phAsset` value, a PHAsset, to get the corresponding PHLivePhoto directly from the photo library yourself.

```
        let asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset
        if let style = asset?.playbackStyle {
            switch style {
            case .livePhoto:
                // hmm, I'm getting .livePhoto but live _is_ nil!
                if live != nil {
                    self.showLivePhoto(live!)
                } else {
                    print("live is nil!")
                    // well then I'll fetch it myself, said the little red hen
                    if let asset = asset {
                        PHImageManager.default().requestLivePhoto(
                            for: asset, targetSize: self.redView.bounds.size, 
                            contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil) { 
                            photo, info in
                            if let photo = photo {
                                self.showLivePhoto(photo)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            // ... other cases ...
            @unknown default: fatalError()
            }
        }
```